# IDA Python recognize same register

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers

As shown in the picture below, `IDA PRO (6.8)` knows to recognize that `al` and `eax` are referencing the same register.

[image]

Given two operands in `IDA Python` (i.e. by `idc.GetOpnd(..)`), how can I find  that they are referencing the same register?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking but AL is part of EAX. `EAX` is the full 32-bit value, `AL` is the lower 8 bits whereas `AH` is the higher 8 bits

Comment: Yes, but my question is how IDA knows to recognize that `EAX`, `AH`, `AL` are part of the same register, and if there's a IDA Python function that could tell me that? As you can see in the picture, choosing `EAX` make `AL` be highlighted too, meaning that there's some king of way that IDA connects between them behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dictionary like this:

```
{ "rax":"rax", "eax":"rax", "ax":"rax" ...  }
```

You can start from the dictionaries contained in https://github.com/angr/archinfo and change it.